# Switching domain names between Azure VMs

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I am currently working with Azure to deploy my app.
I use virtual machines and setup everything internally using ssh directly to the vm.

Also I have a domain name (example.com) that refers (cname) to that machine domain (example.cloudapp.azure.com).

Now I want to raise an entirely new vm and associate the domain name of my app (example.com) to that machine, without causing any downtime. Also I have no access to the configuration of that domain. On other words I want to use some kind of an upper layer in Azure that has it's own domain (example.cloudapp.azure.com) associated to it and lets me configure internally to which vm it should refer at any time.

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to direct all traffics from your app(example.com) to a new vm (new example.cloudapp.azure.com)?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Traffic Manager Profile** in Azure and configure endpoints in many different ways to achieve this - great flexibility is provided.

That’s still only half the solution because you will still need a CNAME record to direct traffic from your domain to yourapp.trafficmanager.net - this is the new destination out of Traffic Manager Profile.

Good news is that you need this CNAME record added just one time. After that you can achieve all future redirecting through Traffic Manager Profile.

Comment: I implemented it using a load balancer and it works... I Traffic Manager Profile sounds like the better idea... Ill take a look and post an answer soon